# Django build is taking so much time in jenkins?

Tags: django, jenkins

I am using jenkins for continuous integration from gitlab and continuous deployment. My "execute shell" consist of the following commands .

```
#!/bin/bash
source /my_env/bin/activate   # Activate the virtualenv
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Operations_central
#pip install -r requirements.txt   # Install or upgrade dependencies
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate                  # Apply South's database        
sudo service nginx restart
fuser -n tcp -k 8088
gunicorn applicationfile.wsgi:application  --bind=myserverip:portno`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's your question? It takes long? Which of the steps takes long? This "question" is pretty hard for us to answer..

Comment: @StephenKing all the steps are executing within a second . But after the last also its keep on building .

Comment: Does `gunicorn`maybe start your application, which continues to run in the foreground?

Comment: @StephenKing ya its taking time because of "gunicorn --bind" command .how to resolve it ?

Comment: Don't start the application? What's the problem that you want to solve?

Comment: @StephenKing "gunicorn applicationfile.wsgi:application  --bind=myserverip:portno" command start the application .But in this way the build is taking too long and "gunicorn applicationfile.wsgi:application  --bind=myserverip:portno --daemon" is not working in jenkins .